Probability - Bayes' theorem
Q. A letter is known to have come either from 'TATA NAGAR' or from 'CALCUTTA'. On the envelope, just two consecutive letters TA are visible. what is the probability that the letter came from 'TATA NAGAR' ?
Should the answer to this question not be $2/3$ as there are 3 possibilities of getting consecutive TA, 2 from Tatanagar and 1 from Calcutta and since favorable outcomes are just 2 so the probability, from tree method, comes out to be $2/3$.
But in the book they have used Bayes' theorem to solve the question and their answer is coming out to be $7/11$.

The ambiguity lies in the wording.  Here, the event that they might be conditioning is maybe that "two letters visible are TA". But whether that is by chance or whether always TA will be visible is not made clear. If the statement was like "any two consecutive letters are randomly seen on the envelope. If it is given that the two consecutive letters seen are TA, then what is the probability that it came from Tata Nagar", then it would have a complicated answer like $\frac{7}{11}$. If it is always the case that only the letters TA are visible, then what you did seems correct to me.

Thanks a lot @Mr. Gandalf Sauron Sir.
The question states that only TA is visible, so cases like CA, TN or CA, NA etc. aren't possible. Therefore why are we taking these cases into account while calculating the probability ?

Was TATA NAGAR written as two words or one? It's spelled as one word in this article. A one word spelling gives $\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{14}}=\frac{7}{11}$.

Your reasoning would only work if each word had the same number of two letter sequences. If, for example, the word with two instances of TA were much larger, than the fact that there are two of them in one word and one in another wouldn't allow us to conclude that the probability that the instance came from the word with two instances is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Bayes' Theorem seems the appropriate tool here
Only two successive letters are visible, and those are TA
In Tatanagar, there are $2$ possibilities for seeing TA against total two successive letter possibilities of $8$
whereas in Calcutta, there is only $1$ possibility of seeing TA against total two successive letter possibilities of $7$
Let $A =$ Tatanagar letter,
$B =$ Calcutta letter,
$C =$ TA seen,
and taking $P(A) = P(B) = 1/2$
$\texttt{(in the absence of any information)}$
$P(C\mid A) = \dfrac{P(A).P(C\mid A)}{P(C)}$
$ - \dfrac{P(A).P(C\mid A)}{P(A).P(C\mid A) +P(B).P(C\mid B)}$
$= \dfrac{(1/2)(2/8)}{(1/2)(2/8)+(1/2)(1/7)} = \dfrac7{11}$

Thanks a lot... but why exactly did the tree method fail in this situation ? were there any cases that were overlooked ?

See, you happen to have seen TA, but you could have seen any two consecutive letters.  Suppose the two cities were KOTA and CALCUTTA, your method would give a probability of $1/2$ which is palpably  unreasonable.

but how can we deduce the information that we can see any 2 consecutive letters from the question ?

You tell me, in the case of Kota vs Calcutta, what would your intuition tell you about the probabilities of seeing TA ? Wouldn't it say that you have probably seen it in the Kota letter ?

The problem is about conditional probability. Bayes' theorem is useful for calculating such probabilities, especially when we want to update our beliefs based on new evidence. In this case, it helps us determine the likelihood (probability) that the letter came from "TATA NAGAR", given that two consecutive letters "TA" are visible.
Let's solve it using Bayes' theorem. Let $X$ be the event that the letter is from "TATA NAGAR". Let $Y$ be the event that the letter is from "CULCUTTA". Also, let $Z$ be the event that two consecutive letters "TA" are visible.
If the letter is from "TATA NAGAR", we see that the events of two consecutive letters visible are TA, AT, TA, AN, NA, AG, GA, and AR. So, $P(Z\mid X)=2/8=1/4$.
And if the letter is from "CALCUTTA", we see that the events of two consecutive letters visible are: CA, AL, LC, CU, UT, TT, and TA. So, $P(Z\mid Y)=1/7$.
Now, the required probability is given by:
$$P(X\mid Z)=\dfrac{P(X)\cdot P(Z\mid X)}{P(X)\cdot P(Z\mid X)+P(Y)\cdot P(Z\mid Y)}=\dfrac{\frac12\cdot\frac14}{\frac12\cdot\frac14+\frac12\cdot\frac17}=\dfrac{7}{11}.$$
Hence, the probability that the letter came from "TATA NAGAR" is $7/11$, slightly less than $2/3$. I hope this helps. Cheers!
PS: Despite having multiple occurrences of "TA" in "TATA NAGAR," the overall likelihood of the letter coming from that source is still lower when considering both options.

Thanks a lot... I wanted to ask why in calculating $P(Z|X)$,we have taken the total possible outcomes as 8 viz. the total possible consecutive letter pairs in TATANAGAR ? could it have been $^9 C_2 = 36$ viz. the total number of 2 letter combinations in TATANAGAR ?

@ca_100 Two "consecutive" letters! So, only 8 possible outcomes as listed in my answer.

I would argue that the problem presented by your textbook is ill defined, and as a result, there are potentially two valid answers. I explain below...
Let $P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR})$ and $P(\texttt{CALCUTTA})$ be the probabilities that the envelope originated from $\texttt{TATA NAGAR}$ and $\texttt{CALCUTTA}$, respectively. Furthermore, let $P(\texttt{TA})$ be the probability of observing the string $\texttt{TA}$ on the envelope.
In the absence of any information about the source of the letter, we have $P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR})=P(\texttt{CALCUTTA})=\frac{1}{2}$. However, you have partial information about the source of the letter, that is, you know the string $\texttt{TA}$ appears on the letter, and you can utilize this information to update your uncertainty about the letter's source. The formula that characterizes this mathematical update is Baye's Theorem, here given by
$P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR|TA}) = \frac{P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR}, \texttt{TA})}{P(\texttt{TA})} = \frac{P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR})P(\texttt{TA}|\texttt{TATA NAGAR}))}{P(\texttt{TA})}$
and we can leverage the law of total probabiltiy to rewrite $P(\texttt{TA}) = P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR}) P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{TATA NAGAR}) + P(\texttt{CALCUTTA}) P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{CALCUTTA})$. Thus,
$P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR|TA}) = \frac{P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR}) P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{TATA NAGAR})}{P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR}) P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{TATA NAGAR}) + P(\texttt{CALCUTTA}) P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{CALCUTTA})}$
To find $P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{TATA NAGAR})$, we must determine the probability of ramdomly observing the string $\texttt{TA}$ given the letter does in fact originate from $\texttt{TATA NAGAR}$. This amounts to counting the number of substrings that read $\texttt{TA}$ among all substrings of length two that appear in the string $\texttt{TATA NAGAR}$. Of course, there are $2$ such substrings, and there are $9$ substrings of length two: $\texttt{TA}, \texttt{AT}, \texttt{TA}, \texttt{A }, \texttt{ N}, \texttt{NA}, \texttt{AG}, \texttt{GA},$ and $\texttt{AR}$. Note that I'm counting white space as a character in the string! Hence, $P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{TATA NAGAR}) = \frac{2}{9}$. As it stands, the problem appears ill defined because it's not exactly clear what "two consecutive letters" means. If it means two letters $\alpha, \beta$ that appear immediately one after the other, then $\texttt{"$\alpha$ $\beta$"} \neq \texttt{"$\alpha\beta$"}$ because white space obstructs. However, if it means two letters $\alpha, \beta$ that appear immediately one after the other while skipping white space, then $\texttt{"$\alpha$ $\beta$"} = \texttt{"$\alpha\beta$"}$ because white space does not count. I'm approaching this problem as a computer scientist, so carefully defined terms, especially with regard to the construction of strings, is a glaring issue to me. If you observe the string through a "window" that is two characters "wide," then you will never observe the string $\texttt{AN}$ from the envelope, but you will see $\texttt{A }$ and $\texttt{ N}$. If white space does not count as a character in the string, then indeed $P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{TATA NAGAR}) = \frac{1}{4}$. In either case, analogous reasoning can be used to easily find $P(\texttt{TA} | \texttt{CALCUTTA}) = \frac{1}{7}$.
By substitution with the above quantities, we have
$P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR|TA}) = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{9}}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{9} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{7}} = \frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{14}} = \frac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{23}{126}} = \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{126}{23} = \frac{14}{23} \approx 0.61$
If white space does not count as a character in the string, then indeed $P(\texttt{TATA NAGAR|TA}) = \frac{7}{11}$

I believe there is a large problem with this question, and insufficient information is provided to be able to answer the question.
But let me try to first explain the answer the book seemed to get ($\frac 7{11}$) and why I think it is invalid.
The premise is that you're only able to see two letters, which means there is a fixed width window that admits visibility of only two letter/character widths. Orientation is a moot point here (that has to be assumed). So we are looking at the number of possible consecutive two letter combinations in each of the strings.
For CALCUTTA, it's unequivocally $7$ possibilities. No argument.
But for TATA NAGAR, I believe your book ignored the space. That's why AN is being considered, when I believe it shouldn't be. The typesetting was explicitly given in the question, and there is a clear space between TATA and NAGAR. Which means if the first letter is the terminal A of TATA, you're not going to see AN in the "window" of 2 characters.
Ignoring the space (as your book did), you get $8$ possible consecutive two letter combinations
But taking the space into account (as I feel it should be), you only get $7$ possible such combinations because A(space) is inadmissible - you would consider that as only having seen one letter, not two.
For TATA NAGAR, two of the possibilities will give you TA, while for CALCUTTA, only one of the possibilities will give you TA.
Now, assuming that the probability of a letter (in general) having come from TATA NAGAR is equal to that of it having come from CALCUTTA, we can work out the required probability both ways using Bayes' Theorem. I think this assumption is actually the fatal flaw that makes the question unanswerable, but I will get to that.
$P(TATA\ NAGAR|TA) = \frac{P(TATA\ NAGAR)\cdot P(TA|TATA\ NAGAR)}{P(TATA\ NAGAR)\cdot P(TA|TATA\ NAGAR) + P(CALCUTTA)\cdot P(TA|CALCUTTA)} \\= \frac{\frac 12\cdot \frac 28}{\frac 12\cdot \frac 28 + \frac 12\cdot \frac 17} \\ = \frac 7{11}$
If you take the space in the typesetting in TATA NAGAR into account, you will get:
$P(TATA\ NAGAR|TA) = \frac{P(TATA\ NAGAR)\cdot P(TA|TATA\ NAGAR)}{P(TATA\ NAGAR)\cdot P(TA|TATA\ NAGAR) + P(CALCUTTA)\cdot P(TA|CALCUTTA)} \\= \frac{\frac 12\cdot \frac 27}{\frac 12\cdot \frac 27 + \frac 12\cdot \frac 17} \\ = \frac 23$
which I actually consider the more reasonable answer to be. Please note that, although you arrived at the answer of $\frac 23$, the logic you used is faulty. What I showed should be the way to arrive at this answer.
However, as I said at the beginning, I consider the question to be fundamentally unanswerable without the additional assumption that it is equiprobable for you to encounter a letter from TATA NAGAR and CALCUTTA in general. This seems a very tenuous assumption as it depends on so many factors (fractional literacy of the respective populations, tendency to use mail as a medium of communication, frequency of letter sends, routing of mail, etc.). To assume both to be equal (and therefore equal to $\frac 12$) is, I think, unfounded. However, without that big assumption, you can't even begin solving this question.
A single line: "You are in a mail room that receives equal volumes of letters from TATA NAGAR and CALCUTTA." would've obviated the issue.
